# explicit formula for $x_n$ in terms of $x_0$, and $a_k$ given recursive formula

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the following formula for $x_n$ in terms of $x_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-1}$. Find a explicit formula for $x_n$ in terms of $x_0$, and all $a_k$.

$$
x_n = \frac{x_{n-1}2^{a_{n-1}} - 1}{3}
$$

For example when n = 1, the formula is as follows.

$$
x_1 = \frac{x_{0}2^{a_{0}} - 1}{3}
$$

When n=2, it is the following.

$$
x_2 = \frac{x_0 2^{a_0 + a_1} - 2^{a_1} - 3}{9}
$$

So, in summary, I want to find an explicit formula for $x_n$ in the general case for any $n$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: using the method described in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients). I was able to find a formula for $x_n$ in terms of $A_0$, but I am not sure how to find $A_0$.

Comment: After looking into it further, I think $A_0 = x_0$.

Comment: What are the $a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I base this suggestion on the cases $n=0,1,2,3$ and assuming that the $a_n$ are at least real/complex numbers such that you can sum them up. Also empty sums where the upper index is smaller than the lower are assumed to be zero, i.e., if $m>n$ we have $\sum_{i=m}^n f_i =0$ for any sequence $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then (to be proven by you)

$$x_n = \dfrac{x_0 2^{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}3^{n-1-k} 2^{\sum_{i=1}^ka_{n-i}}}{3^n}$$

Via induction you get the proof in a few lines because the calculations are straight forward.